# google now not showing event registration card

Tags: google-now

I am able to see the event in email but not in Google Now app. I am triggering email from Google App Script. The markup has been verified by Google's markup tester and is valid. Below is JSON-LD format:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber": "IO123456789",
      "modifyReservationUrl": "http://www.searshomeservices.com",
      "modifiedTime": "2015-03-04T02:30:00-06:00",
      "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "John Smith"
      },
      "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
      "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "Event",
        "name": "Event Confirmation",
        "startDate": "2015-03-05T04:30:00-06:00",
 "performer": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Jitendra",
      "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-qYfc01xZOSg/Uw46cceE_EI/AAAAAAAAABw/xNYxVibhDSs/s70-no/cara_verde.png"
    },
        "location": {
          "@type": "Place",
          "name": "Moscone Center",
          "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "800 W Howard St.",
            "addressLocality": "Chicago",
            "addressRegion": "IL",
            "postalCode": "60626",
            "addressCountry": "US"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I tested the markup you posted, except I changed the startDate property to ("startDate": "2015-06-02T16:30:00-08:00"). 

In result, I was able to generate Now cards on my iPhone and HTC one device.  Card on iPhone (http://i.stack.imgur.com/pPA2z.png), card on HTC One (http://i.stack.imgur.com/iaQPT.png).

Have you checked your settings (to show cards)? Have you tried testing on more than one device?

Comment: @Anuj - could you try using the above markup and just updating the startDate property to see if you can trigger a Now card.

Comment: @Franco Thanks for replying. Please see my code here: https://ideone.com/cZ3D8N. I can see other cards from email.

Comment: @Anuj I just checked out your code:

Replace: "@context" : "http://s...content-available-to-author-only...a.org"

With: "@context" : "http://schema.org"

Replace: "reservationStatus" : "http://s...content-available-to-author-only...a.org/ReservationConfirmed"

With: "reservationStatus" : "http://schema.org/Confirmed"

I changed those, along with the startDate property (todays date), in result generated a Now card: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb6L7.png